# Bloc not updating state. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code. This is my first try with bloc architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc, dart-pub

Bloc not updating state. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code. There are two buttons, first one triggers first event and the second button triggers second event. But the state is not updating in my case. I dont know why this is not updating state in my case.

bloc class

```
  class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  MyBloc() : super(LoadingState());

  @override`enter code here`
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    if (event is FirstEvent) {
      yield* firstFunction();
    } else if (event is SecondEvent) {
      yield* secondFunction();
    }
  }

  Stream<MyState> firstFunction() async* {
    yield LoadingState();
    try {
      final String name = Repository().getFirstName();
      yield FirstState(name: name);
    } on Exception {
      yield ErrorState();
    } catch (_) {
      yield ErrorState();
    }
  }

  Stream<MyState> secondFunction() async* {
    yield LoadingState();
    try {
      final String name = Repository().getLastName();
      yield SecondState(name: name);
    } on Exception {
      yield ErrorState();
    } catch (_) {
      yield ErrorState();
    }
  }
}
```

event class

```
@immutable
abstract class MyEvent extends Equatable {
  const MyEvent();
}

class FirstEvent extends MyEvent {
  const FirstEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SecondEvent extends MyEvent {
  const SecondEvent();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

state class

```
@immutable
abstract class MyState extends Equatable {
  const MyState();
}

class LoadingState extends MyState {
  const LoadingState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class FirstState extends MyState {
  const FirstState({required this.name});
  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SecondState extends MyState {
  const SecondState({required this.name});
  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [name];
}

class ErrorState extends MyState {
  const ErrorState();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

repository

```
class Repository {
  /// get data from api
  String getFirstName() {
    return "First name";
  }

  String getLastName() {
    return "last name";
  }
}
```

homescreen

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyBloc _myBloc = MyBloc();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
          ),
          BlocBuilder<MyBloc, MyState>(builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoadingState) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (state is FirstState) {
              return Text(state.name);
            } else if (state is SecondState) {
              return Text(state.name);
            } else if (state is ErrorState) {
              return Text("Error");
            }
            return const SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Text('Something went wrong!'),
            );
          }),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async{
              _myBloc.add(FirstEvent());
              await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 200,
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Show First Name"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async{
              _myBloc.add(SecondEvent());
              await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
            },
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              width: 200,
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Show Last Name"),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

main function

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

my app

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => MyBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(**strong text**
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is how you're initializing your `MyBloc` instance.

Check out [the docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts) for more info but basically instead of this

```
MyBloc _myBloc = MyBloc();
```

Initialize your `MyBloc` like this in your build method so it has access to context.

```
final _myBloc = context.read<MyBloc>();
```

That should update your state.